# Maya bay closed? Help required for planning phi phi island stay

Tags: thailand, phi-phi

I am going to Thailand next week. Particulary Phuket, krabi, phi phi island, Bangkok.
I heard Maya bay in phi phi island is closed indefinitely for rehabilitation. That was one of my main interests in visiting phi phi island. Now that it is closed how can I plan my 2 day stay at phi phi?

EDIT: To make this question more objective, I ask: Apart from Maya bay, what other places are most visited (statistically) in phi phi island?.

Comment: There's an article on BBC about it here: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/resources/idt-sh/the_beach_nobody_can_touch

Comment: Sorry but editing from "Where should I go?" to "What are the statistically most visited places?" is just an attempt to create a loophole. We're not writing a tourist guide for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the impression from news reports that many of the visitors to Maya Bay were quite disappointed with the crowds of boats and thousands of tourists blocking their "perfect" view, and it was nothing like the environment seen in the film *The Beach*.  A recent report on the BBC showed steps taken to prevent tourist boats from entering the bay itself, the program for restoration of coral that had been damaged by boats, and the re-emergence of species like black-tip reef sharks.

Meanwhile neighbouring Ko Phi Phi Don, while it is a larger island with resorts, bars, restaurants and other tourist infrastructure, also has a number of beaches away from the main tourist hotels, some are accessible by foot, others by boat.